# Dit-on « les personnes en souffrance » pour désigner les personnes qui souffrent ?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai vu les expressions « les personnes en souffrance » « les personnes en souffrance psychique » sur certains sites français :
[Sos fin de vie](https://www.sosfindevie.org/4-cles-pour-accompagner-une-personne-en-souffrance/),
[Fondation de France](https://www.fondationdefrance.org/fr/appels-a-projets/sante-mentale-des-exiles-accompagner-les-personnes-en-souffrance-psychique)

Mais selon le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souffrance), « en souffrance » signifie « en attente de parvenir à son destinataire ou d'être retiré(e) par lui », etc.

Comment: Le vrai terme 100% politiquement correct, c'est : "les personnes en situation de souffrance psychique" :D Plus sérieusement, c'est une question de registre de langage. "Qui souffrent" a l'avantage de ne pas cacher la réalité derrière un surplus verbal...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/souffrance) :

> **Souffrance** :
> Fait de souffrir. *La souffrance au travail. La souffrance animale.*
> – *Être en souffrance* : souffrir psychiquement. *Adolescents en
> souffrance*.

C'est aussi le sens du mot *souffrance* que le TLFi donne dans son **I**. Le TLFi ne donne tout simplement pas d'exemple du mot employé dans ce sens là précédé de la préposition *en*.

La locution adverbiale *en souffrance* employé pour des objets  correspond à un autre sens du mot « souffrance » (un retard préjudiciable), le TLFi donne ce sens en **II**, en indiquant que ça correspond à un sens différent du verbe *souffrir*, et on ne trouve plus guère cet emploi que dans la locution *en souffrance*.

Et pour répondre à la question posée, bien sûr qu'on parle de personnes en souffrance, il suffit de voir les emplois dans les publications spécialisées : c'est courant admis et compris. Et on ne dit pas *être en souffrance* dans le sens « d'aller mal » uniquement pour les personnes. Depuis quelques années, on parle beaucoup, par exemple, de « l'hôpital en souffrance » et de la « santé en souffrance », où l'on peut se demander s'il n'y a pas de double sens impliqué : malade et en suspens...

Comment: Merci, c'est très clair !